# how to prevent normal users to access the particular html page in django?

Tags: python, django

I have post creation HTML page in my django project ,I need that page to be accessed only by the admin.
Is there any way to prevent the normal user to access the post creation page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, we use decorators to allow users with certain permissions to access a view.

Derived from [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator):

```
@login_required
@permission_required('post_creator.read', raise_exception=True)
def post_creator(request):
    ...
```

Alternatively, you can use [`user.has_perm()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#default-permissions) to check if a user has the required permission in code. But function decorators are the preferred way to do "page restriction" in Django.

---

To give a permission to a user.

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Page X access')
my_user.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

---

I strongly suggest you to read more about permissions [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization).